# Positioning a caption over a background using Rmagick or ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

I have a background image that I want to add a text box to.

I am trying to figure out how to position a caption in the right spot on top of it. (I'm using caption because I need the word wrap feature).

Right now, I'm only able to get the text to show on the *top left corner*, but I need to be able to manually position where it starts.

```
require 'RMagick'
require 'Pry'
include Magick

text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

img =  ImageList.new('template001.jpg')
img <<  Magick::Image.read("caption:#{text}") {
  self.fill = '#FFFFFF'
  self.font = "Helvetica"
  self.pointsize = 32
  self.size = "550x400"
  self.background_color = "none"
}.first

a = img.flatten_images

a.write("out.jpg")
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is an answer for the ImageMagick command line using `convert`. If you want to use this method with Rmagick, you'll have to port it yourself.

1. **Size of the text box.** When you use `-size NxM caption:"some text"`, the text will fit automatically into the box with the size `NxM`.
2. **Basic location of the text box.** You can use `-gravity` with arguments. Possible basic arguments are: *None,
   Center,
   East,
   Forget,
   NorthEast,
   North,
   NorthWest,
   SouthEast,
   South,
   SouthWest,
   West.*

   These basic `-gravity` operators place the text box into the obvious spots indicated by their "speaking" names.
3. **Finer-grained location setting.** However, you can additionally use `-geometry +X+Y` to shift the exact locations by a number of pixels (`+X` shifts X pixels to the right, `-X` shifts to the left; `+Y` pushes by Y pixels to the top, `-Y` pushes towards the bottom).

Let's use a box with 270 pixels width and 70 pixels height. Here is the command I used, at first with a short text:

```
mytext="Cheers\!"

convert                            \
  -background '#0008'              \
  -gravity center                  \
  -fill white                      \
  -size 260x70 caption:"${mytext}" \
   funny-santa.jpg                 \
  +swap                            \
  -gravity south                   \
  -composite                       \
   funny-santa---1.jpg
```

Here is the result (original image on top, image with text on bottom):

[image]
[image]

If you want to put longer text into the same box, just use longer text :-)

Look here:

```
mytext="Dear Kids\! One day you'll learn everything about Santa Claus. On that day, please also remember what they told you about Jesus."

convert                            \
  -background '#0008'              \
  -gravity center                  \
  -fill white                      \
  -size 260x70 caption:"${mytext}" \
   funny-santa.jpg                 \
  +swap                            \
  -gravity south                   \
  -composite                       \
   funny-santa---2.jpg
```

[image]

Now shift the text box by 60 pixels to the right and by 30 pixels to the top:

```
mytext="Dear Kids\! Pushing text boxes around to place captions at precise locations inside an image is easy."

convert                            \
  -background '#0008'              \
  -gravity center                  \
  -geometry +60+30                 \
  -fill white                      \
  -size 260x70 caption:"${mytext}" \
   funny-santa.jpg                 \
  +swap                            \
  -gravity south                   \
  -composite                       \
   teaching-santa.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `Magick::RVG` for this:

```
# Create a canvas of the required size
rvg = Magick::RVG.new(550, 400) do |canvas|

  # Set the background image
  canvas.background_image = Magick::Image.read("bg.jpg").first

  # Create a style group for font and fill options
  canvas.g.styles(font_size: 21, fill: "#FFFFFF", font: "Helvetica") do |grp|

    # Output text at the desired location
    grp.text(150, 150, "caption:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
  end
end

# Extract canvas as an image
img = rvg.draw

# Set the color profile to sRGB
img.colorspace = RGBColorspace

# Output as a PNG (you'll want to write this output to a file or save in a db)
img.to_blob { self.format = 'PNG' }
```

Comment: A word of caution: RVG does not support any sort of text wrapping as far as I know. I found this out the hard way. If you need text wrapping, your only option is to create a caption. Text wrapping aside, I prefer RVG because it's easier to position precisely atop another image using `composite`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Magick::Draw](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html), and query text metrics to position text.

```ruby
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

text = "Hello\nworld"

img = ImageList.new('wizard:')
draw = Draw.new() {
  self.fill = '#FF00FF'
  self.font = "Helvetica"
  self.pointsize = 32
}
draw.text_align(RightAlign)
# Query font metrics for positioning (or get_multiline_type_metrics)
text_metrics = draw.get_type_metrics(text)
draw.text(img.columns, text_metrics.height, text)
draw.draw(img)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control where the text appears over the image. Effectively you create two separate images and them composite them together afterwards.

`canvas` is the base image you want to composite on top of. `overlay_text` is the text block that will go on top.

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

the_text = 'This is the text how will it wrap????'
canvas = ImageList.new("some_input_file.png") 

overlay_text = Image.read("caption:#{the_text}") do
  self.size = "300x200"
  self.font = "Tahoma"
end.first

result = canvas.composite(overlay_text, Magick::CenterGravity, 0,-30, Magick::OverCompositeOp)

result.write('out.png')
```

The `overlay_text` block uses [caption](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption) which will automatically scale `the_text` to fit within `self.size`.

You can fix the font size with `self.pointsize = 20` if you want to but if your text is bigger than than fits in the size you define it will be cropped.

Once you have your two images you can do a composite using `Image#composite(source_image, gravity, x, y, composite_operator)` which gives you the standard gravity and x & y offset controls. In this instance the text overlay is composited 30 pixels up from the centre of the base canvas image.